# Usage of "any" When asking questions

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

Which of the following sentences is correct? And what's the difference?

1. **Have any students** in this university  come from Australia to study here?
2. **Has any student** in this university  come from Australia to study here?

I think only the second sentence is correct. Can native speakers please answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both questions are correct. The subject verb agreement rules apply regardless of whether a sentence is a statement or a question.

To me, the first sentence sounds less stilted since normally when you are asking a question like this, you would want to know **all** of the students in the university that have come from Australia and not just one of them.

The second statement also implies in a way that there is only one student from Australia that is studying at the university.

A similar question—[Use “have” or “has” any/anyone/anything in the question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144806/use-have-or-has-any-anyone-anything-in-the-question)— was asked on EL&U